# Error in the VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

The aim of my code is to print available if there is any data betweeen L1 to W1000 of length 7.

Although it finds the value of length 7, my code doesn't obey exit for.

what is the reason?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Prod As Variant
Dim Dev As Variant
Dim counter As Integer
Dim j As Variant

Prod = Array("PBA_100", "PCA_500", "PRD_500", "PGA_500", "PVD_500")

For j = LBound(Prod) To UBound(Prod)
     MsgBox Prod(j)

 With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(j))
 LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(j)).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", 
 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("N2:N" & LastRow)
        arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ")
        For Each arrElem In arr
            If Len(arrElem) = 7 Then
            MsgBox arrElem
        Exit For
      Else
      MsgBox arrElem
            End If
        Next arrElem
    Next cell
 End With

Next j

End Sub
```

Comment: Where `k` is defined?

Comment: k is defined at the top
i have only included the part where i have the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exit the nested for loop, if you find `available` value. Like this:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(j))
LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Prod(j)).Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", 
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For Each cell In .Range("L1:W1000", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        arr = Split(Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " "), " ")
        For Each arrElem In arr
            If Len(arrElem) = 7 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & k).Value = "available"
            Exit For 'You exit only the nested loop here!
            Else
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & k).Value = "NOT available"
            End If
        Next arrElem
    Next cell
End With
```

Comment: @AnirudhChauhan - start debugging step by step with `F8` and try paying attention what `arrElem` is and its value. For example add `debug.print arrElem` before the `If Len(arrElem)=7`. Hopefully, after about 30 minutes of pressing `F8` you would see the solution.